# Logarithmic convexity of incomplete gamma function.

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-distributions, convex-analysis, gamma-distribution

[The incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) $F(t)$ satisfies

$$
1 - F(t) \sim \int^\infty_t dx \, e^{-x} x^{\alpha - 1}
$$

for $t > 0$ and its derivative $F^\prime \sim e^{-t} t^{\alpha - 1}$ is the density function of [the Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

[It is claimed](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366b.htm) that the hazard rate, also known as [the failure rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate)

$$h = -\frac{d}{dt} \ln (1 - F) = \frac{F^\prime}{1-F}$$

is **increasing everywhere** (i.e. $h^\prime (t) > 0$) for the case that $\alpha > 1$ and **decreasing everywhere** for the case that $\alpha < 1$.

In other words, the [logarithmic convexity of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function) $1 - F$ depends only on the sign of $\alpha - 1$.

This result is also given as a proof exercise in problem 5.22 of [this book](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Ross-First-Course-in-Probability-A-10th-Edition/PGM1786065.html).

It's unclear to me how to prove this result. We have

$$ h^\prime = \frac{(1-F)F^{\prime \prime} + (F^\prime)^2}{(1-F)^2} = \frac{F^\prime}{(1-F)^2} \left[ (1-F)\left(\frac{\alpha - 1}{t} - 1 \right) + F^\prime \right], $$

but from this point the next step is unclear.

Comment: I gave up trying to solve this, but you may want to use the fact that $\dfrac{1}{1-F(t)}$ is nondecreasing merely by definition of $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $t=0$. Then, $h(0)=0$ and since for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $h(\epsilon) > 0$, the derivative (to the right) at zero is positive. (I assume we can omit to consider $t<0$).

Now, consider $t > 0$. On this set, $1/h$ is well defined and given by
$$1/h = \int_t^{\infty} dx e^{t-x} \left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^{\alpha - 1}$$
Doing a change of variable, we get
$$1/h = \int_0^{\infty} dx e^{-x} \left(1+\frac{x}{t}\right)^{\alpha - 1}$$

Now, note that the term
$$\left(1+\frac{x}{t}\right)^{\alpha - 1}$$
increases (decreases) in $t$ if $\alpha<1$ ($\alpha>1$).

The claim then follows.

Comment: yes $t > 0$, I accidentally left that out of the question, but I just made an edit.